# Dialogflow v2 user input and fulfillment

Tags: dialogflow-es, fulfillment

I am writing a Dialogflow v2 chatbot with Actions on Google.

I am asking for users to create a list and then have the option for ordering them.

I need to get a few pieces of information from the user. Her name, phone number and address.

Then I need the name of the vendor and their mobile number where the order will be forwarded.

If they have already given their name, I want to show it to them and have them confirm it. 
The problem is that everything is an intent.
As an example they say Order from my list. I have to ask them for a store name e.g. Walmart. Now the problem is that I may not have all the vendors in an entity list. And if they just say Walmart, how do I know if it's a vendor name. I know I could have a follow up intent but not sure what happens when they don't say the right thing.

Basically, this is how I want the conversation to go.

They create a list which I have working.

Then they say order from list

Chatbot ask for the name of the store and mobile number to order from
Chatbot checks the name in the database and if doesn't exist adds it.

Asks for name, number address of the user

Shows the order, the vendor and the user's name and address

Passes this information to the server fulfillment hook.

Next time it needs to sense that it knows the user name, address and number and ask the user to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, you would need to rely on contexts and webhook for validating the store name.

- If the store is not valid, [reset the context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51769678/how-to-reset-a-parameter-value-so-agent-can-ask-for-the-parameter-again/51770790#51770790) (same as input) and politely ask the user to provide the right store name.
- Maintain a counter in [parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51521454/how-to-save-data-between-conversation-in-dialogflow/51521878#51521878) to keep track of the number of wrong attempts.
- Increment that counter when wrong, reset when correct.
- If the counter reaches 3 or 4, politely reply back that you could not serve them this that vendor and ask them to try the app later.

If this assistant app is US based you may need to add Transaction API as well to show the final order and confirm back to the user. Transaction API is available in the US as of now so keep that in mind.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you be more specific with an example? 
I don't have the store names in a list unfortunately. The store can be a new store so it may not be in the entity list. So I can't really validate it, nor use slot filling.
I do know about the Transaction API but thanks.
The problem is also this, if the user says Veggie Reggie, I may not know it's a store. 
So should I say say store and store name? That is the only way I can be sure that she is entering a store name.

Comment: Also, I am using MySQL to store user's queries and data so probably don't need parameters.

Comment: You may need to manually update store names in DB and in the entity for the stores you are supporting. Those outside that list should be either entered by user with a separate flow all together or you may ask user to try with different stores as you are not supporting the current one.